# Relation between chain rule and implicit differentiation derivation in multi variable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, implicit-differentiation

So my question is on the [derivation of the implicit differentiation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5grx.png) (taken from [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx)).

The general chain rule, from [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx), it says that if we have a function $z$ of $n$ variables, $x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and each of these variables are in turn a function of $m$ variables, $t_1, t_2,\ldots, t_m$.  Then for any $t_i, i=1, 2, \ldots, m$ we have (1) 
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial t_i}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial t_i}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial t_i}+\cdots+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_n}\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial t_i}$$

My question is how does did the differentiation of $F$ with respect to $x$ come up as it did.  How did it come up as (2) $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\cdots+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$$
If I match (2) with (1), then it seems that the left hand side is $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ because $F=z, x=x_1, y=x_2, z=x_3$.  As far as the initial condition of $F$ having three variables $(x, y, z)$ that in turn are each supposed to be functions of more variables, can it be assumed that $x$ and $y$ are constants; this would be mean effectively that $x=g(t_1, t_2, t_3)=x$ of some function g and $y=y(t_1, t_2, t_3)=y$.  So is the left hand side of (2) $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ or some different notation.  What does the differentiation of $F$ with respect to $x$ on the left hand side look like in symbols then?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to improve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When god created the world  there were three independent quantities $x$, $y$, $z$ changing with time, say. Then a physicist came and said: These three quantities are related by a so-and-so equation $$F(x,y,z)=0\ .\tag{1}$$
At any rate, at some instant $t_0$ of time one indeed had $F(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0$. The equation $(1)$ connecting the three quantities $x$, $y$, $z$ reduces the degrees of freedom by $1$. Therefore we have the feeling that, given two values $x$ and $y$, the value of $z$ should be determined by $(1)$, at least in the neighborhood of the point $P_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. This means that there should be a function $z=\psi(x,y)$ defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$ and giving $\psi(x_0,y_0)=z_0$, such that
$$F\bigl(x,y, \psi(x,y)\bigr)=0\qquad\forall (x,y)\in U\ .\tag{2}$$
Sometimes we can explicitly solve $(1)$ for $z$, and then we have this $\psi$ as a a function of the variables $x$ and $y$ "in finite terms". But in most cases we can't. That's where the *implicit function theorem* comes in. It says that such a function $z=\psi(x,y)$ defined in the neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ indeed exists, and that this $\psi$ is even differentiable.  In particular, we are able to compute the partial derivatives $\psi_x(x_0,y_0)$ and $\psi_y(x_0,y_0)$ from the given data. The chain rule allows to argue as follows: From $(2)$ we obtain by differentiating with respect to $x$ and putting $(x,y):=(x_0,y_0)$ afterwards:
$$F_{.1}(x_0,y_0,z_0)\cdot 1+F_{.3}(x_0,y_0,z_0)\psi_x(x_0,y_0)=0\ .$$
This gives
$$\psi_x(x_0,y_0)=-{F_{.1}(x_0,y_0,z_0)\over F_{.3}(x_0,y_0,z_0)}\ ,\tag{3}$$
under the "technical assumption" $$F_{.3}(x_0,y_0,z_0)\ne0\ .\tag{4}$$ The formula $(3)$ is usually written in the shorthand version
$${\partial z\over\partial x}\biggr|_{(x_0,y_0)}=-{F_x\over F_z}\biggr|_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}\ .$$
Similarly, one has
$${\partial z\over\partial y}\biggr|_{(x_0,y_0)}=-{F_y\over F_z}\biggr|_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)}\ .$$
Note that the assumption  $(4)$ is essential for all this to hold.

Comment: $F_{.1}(x_0,y_0,z_0)\cdot 1+F_{.3}(x_0,y_0,z_0)\psi_x(x_0,y_0)=0\ .$ is $=0$ because derivative of constant function is 0? (is $F$ called a function here or an equation?)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it will be much easier if you use total differential concept
$$F\big(x,y,z\big)=0$$
$$dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}dz=0$$
Note that $z=z(x,y)$ and therefore
$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy$$
If $dz$ plugged in
$$dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy\bigg)=0$$
$$dF=\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)dx+\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \bigg)dy=0$$
The equality holds for any $dx$ and $dy$ if
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)=0 \Rightarrow\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}}$$
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg)=0 \Rightarrow\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}}$$